# DC-DC Isolated converter gets really hot

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter

I'm building a prototype using CUI isolated DC-DC converter ([This one](https://www.cui.com/product/resource/pcn2-s.pdf)). It's currently working but I notice that the converters get really hot. Am I missing something? This is the schematic [image]

[image: PCB]

[image: Jacks]

Comment: "Required to add a 2.2 µF (5 & 12 Vdc input models) or 10 µF (24 Vdc input models) ceramic capacitor to the input to reduce input voltage stress." <- Not sure if that would cause it to overheat but probably not helping that you didn't bypass the device.

Comment: Why the 317 preregulator? That seems nonsensical here, when you could just choose a switching converter that can directly accept whatever your input voltage is.

Comment: 'Really hot' is what temperature, quantitatively? With full load (which is?)? With no load?  Why is the DC input marked AC1/AC2? What are the measured converter output voltages - could unused connectors be shorting the outputs because the connections are incorrect and they have a switch?

Comment: I guess you placed all of them right next to each other so heat accumulates between the converters? 
Did you do temperature measurements to quantify "really hot"?
Can we see a picture of the finished PCB?

Comment: Hi Sebastián, welcome to EE.SE! Your question as it is now is very vague, and cannot be answered. You should read Spehro's comment, and add all that extra information to your question. Otherwise your question may be closed for being too unclear.

Comment: hi @SpehroPefhany, I don't have the means to do a quantitative measurement but it gets hot up to just below the point where it would burn your finger when placed over it, it just warm. I'm connecting guitar pedals to each output so the load is very small (few mA's) I tried using all four connectors and those who get hottest are those in the middle. All voltages are 8.88v which is what I want. I added a picture of the PCB

Comment: @SebastiánPabloSimone So probably in the 60°C range, give or take. Your build does not match the schematic. I see a common wire on the connectors, for example. Can you post a better photo of the connectors and link the datasheet?

Comment: Hi @SpehroPefhany, thank you for replying. The lower 4 jacks are daisy chained from the lower regulator (IC3) My idea was to use the upper 4 ones as isolated jacks that don't share a ground and the lower for with a common ground to improve noise on the PSU and also to allow negative ground and positive ground connections.

Comment: @SebastiánPabloSimone Ok. I don't see anything obvious wrong, maybe someone else can.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I have to say that I added the preregulator out of pure ignorance as I'm feeding the circuit with a switching power supply, but I'm not sure that this is causing the heat. Can the closeness between the units the culprit, as  S_G mentions  ?

Comment: When i looked at the datasheet I didn't see enough information to tell without actual measurements.. however that seems like an awful lot of losses for an assumed relatively low current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On page 6 of the datasheet you linked, it says the efficiency drops to 35% at 10 mA. For the "few mA" current that you are drawing, the efficiency would be even lower.

I would say add a small fan (3W - 5W) to blow air over the converters and don't worry too much about it.

In addition, add a 10uF capacitor (preferably ceramic) very close to the input terminals of each converter.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this topology is poor - using a linear regulator to feed a switcher and then back to a linear regulator is bad design for the unnecessary complexity, added heat generated, and reduced reliability.

Assuming you are not overloading the supplies and the voltage limits aren't exceeded, the problem is likely the physical proximity of "stacking" the supplies as depicted. First, you want to leave adequate space between the supplies for thermal management. But more importantly in this case, you're going to have interactions between the magnetics of the supplies. In other words, because the switchers are identical, the inductors are located in exactly the same location causing instability in the internal control loops causing severe losses in the mosfets. Ideally, you would want these supplies arranged 90 degrees apart to minimize that issue. Even better, just use one larger dcdc supply assuming you don't need isolation between the channels.

Comment: The magnetic interaction concern is assuming the converters use unshielded inductors. Given that they're isolated, they might not use plain inductors at all, and just use transformers, which would have relatively little coupling outside the module.